# Is it possible to get the geolocation coordinates of electronic device using MAC address..?

Tags: geolocation, iot, mac-address

Device is either connected or not-connected to internet. In which scenario it is possible to get the geolocation coordinates using MAC.

Comment: yes, google geolocation api, mozilla geolocation api

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate a wifi or a cellphone tower there are databases to do so, however I couldn't find a database in fact, only an online service, but behind it should be a database, and you need to enter the data manually. You could also locate a cellphone if you know the mac address of the WIFI or cellphone tower where it is connected, but have access to that info wont be that easy.

I found [this](https://wigle.net/), and it is really impressive the amount of data however I couldn't find my wifi there, I guess is not simple to get the location for all the wifi in the world... except for google.
https://wigle.net/

How ever locate people won't be that easy, no one would like the possibility of being easily located by anybody anytime and quickly.

Example about how google uses that info:

https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/1725632?hl=en

Comment: Thanx Adrian. This will help me in some cases.